# Python subprocess popen scp trigger the sshd on remote host and won't stop automatically when the scp done

Tags: python, cmd, cygwin, popen, scp

It's my first time asking a question.
For some reason, I use python to transfer files from A to B, where A and B are both Windows 10 and installed Cygwin.
And default shell for Host B is Cygwin.
So if I try to log in the host B, I will start a Cygwin shell instead of Windows Powershell.

Part of my code is following:

```
send_cmd = subprocess.Popen(['scp', '-pr', logfile, 'userB@hostB:~/path/to/'])
```

This is actually calling windows console to do 'scp'.
And after this process is done, I checked the task manager on Host B, it seems that Cygwin created another sshd service to handle 'scp', but not automatically closed when 'scp' is done.
And this new 'sshd' service consumes Host B 20% CPU resource.
Every time I do the 'scp' process, one more sshd service will be created.
Soon, the Host B CPU resource is run out and the host just gets stuck.
I tried PowerShell as well, but still the same situation.
I thought it's the problem between cmd/PowerShell and Cygwin since there's no problem when I use Cygwin to do 'scp'.
So, I managed to have python popen to execute Cygwin. However, to no avail.

I add Cygwin/bin to windows environment path and tried:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen('bash -c \"scp -pr file.txt UserB@HostB:~\"'
```

But still, make a new sshd on Host B.
I have tried a lot of other solutions, to no avail.

Is there anyone who can point out where the problem is? What is the point I didn't see?

Comment: Are the file copied or not ?

Comment: Yes, the 'scp' process is correctly done without any standard error.